# Windows Edge and opening a blob url

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, bloburls

I'm getting some odd results when trying to open a new window with a blob url in Windows Edge (20.10240.16384, which is the version in the IE11 VM supplied by Microsoft).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', sourceUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e,form) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob = this.response;
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var w = window.open(url);
    }
}
```

On the line

```
var w = window.open(url);
```

I'm getting an "Access is denied" error which looks to be tied up with CORS ,which makes sense a little as it's not technically the same domain. However a BLOB url doesn't technically have a domain?

Is this a bug in Edge? Or am I doing something not quite right? This code works in IE, Chrome etc.

Comment: any luck with this one? I'm having errors like this reported on data created on the client itself.  My google-fu hasn't uncovered a solution yet...

Comment: I ended up rewriting it to not get use blob urls. So no I haven't uncovered a fix for doing it this way yet.

Comment: old post- But what did u use instead of blob urls?

Comment: installing latest version edge (80.x and above) resolves this

Answer (score 15):

I found out the solution on both IE and Edge.

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);  
 }
 else {
     var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(objectUrl);  
}
```

The link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463901/setting-window-location-or-window-open-in-angularjs-gives-access-is-denied-in)

Comment: do you know if this will work if IE or Edge has adblock plus or something of the sort that blocks opening popups silently? For non IE i ended up using window.location which does not trigger a new tab. I don't know about IE/Edge if it has a msLoadBlobInCurrentTab so to say...

Comment: i try your code but not working in Edge.

Comment: not working. In IE it is showing access denied exception. I have a blob response object. I have to download that. So creating url like let url = URL.createobjecturl(blob); window.open(url); this is working fine in chrome. But in IE it is not working. So here I had to use msSaveOrOpenBlob. Here file is getting downloaded but it is not able to open automatically in a new tab like chrome. So is there any way to achieve it in Edge. @ Irvin Dominin