# window.url.createobjecturl(blob) not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge, pdf.js

Firstly, I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no the success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**Search Questions**:

[Displaying Blob PDF in Edge/IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505424/displaying-blob-pdf-in-edge-ie11)

[Windows Edge and opening a blob URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217537/windows-edge-and-opening-a-blob-url)

[Blob download is not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310688/blob-download-is-not-working-in-ie)

I've searched related questions and tried to write the code but not had any success. I work with the PDFJS Project. I have open blob file in new tap. The below code works in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) but it's not working in Edge. I also use `viewer.js` in my project. I want to load my PDF file in Edge browser **Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0**.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/pdfblob.aspx', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
  window.open('/web/viewer.html?file=' + url);
};
xhr.send();
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: The error in Edge is due to the file not being served to the request, not to do with your JS logic which should work. Try clearing the browser cache to ensure the latest version of the file is being retrieved.

Comment: i try to this but not load data.

Comment: Also note `Window` should be `window` and `createObjectUR` should be `createObjectURL`, but I assume they are just typos as your code would not work at all, otherwise

Comment: Are you trying to parse this `?file` query param from your server??? That won't work, for sure, but not only in Edge.

Comment: ?file query param work on all browser.

Comment: i have same requirement.. @Sumit patel is your issue resolved?

Comment: @SathishKotha no