# (Angular) Need help to download a cvs file in IE, it works on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, blob

> This works on chrome and firefox, but i need this in IE, i don't know
> how to make it works. Internet Explorer console says "access denied"

```
descargarPlantilla() {
    this.cargaMasivaService.generarCSVPLD().subscribe(
      data => {
        const blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        const contentDisposition = data.headers.get('content-disposition');
        if (contentDisposition && contentDisposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
          const filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
          const matches = filenameRegex.exec(contentDisposition);
        }
        this.modalMensajeService.modalExito('El Documento se ha descargado exitosamente');
      },
      error => {
        this.modalMensajeService.modalError(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you download the csv file as you don't show it in your example code. But I think the error is due to you're using some methods not supported by IE.

IE has [its own API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh779016(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for creating and downloading files, which is called `msSaveBlob` or `msSaveOrOpenBlob`. You should use one of them to download files. The difference between the `msSaveBlob` and `msSaveOrOpenBlob` methods is that the former only provides a **Save** button to the user whereas the latter provides both a **Save** and an **Open** button.

If you have the blob data, you can use the API like this:

```
if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    //IE11 & Edge, download function
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName); 
}
else{
   //Other browsers, your download function        
    ...
}
```

You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175099/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-access-is-denied-in-ie-browsers-when-downloading-a) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257336/downloading-a-dynamic-csv-in-internet-explorer) for more information.